# When are JavaScript's native prototype shared among same-origin frames?

Tags: javascript, iframe, prototype

Today I observed that for some iframes of www.cnn.com (`window[0]` in the example), they have

```
Array.prototype === window[0].Array.prototype
```

Of course, from within the frame they also have

```
Array.prototype === top.Array.prototype
```

same goes for `Object`, `Function` etc. But I can't find any information about this behavior, and I can't reproduce it if I create a plunkr with a same-origin iframe. The main page and the frame both set their `document.domain` to `cnn.com`, but this doesn't seem to help in my case either. `Array.prototype` is not configurable so it's not clear to me how could this be done on purpose by a script. I experienced this (but could not replicate it) on FF 29, not on Chrome 33.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused about what your question is, but I assume you are asking Why would there be a need to share Native object prototypes across frames. In a normal situation you wouldn't and this condition would be the case
`false == (<Iframe>.window.Array.prototype === window.Array.prototype)` I'm guessing they are attempting to force this conditional to be true across documents.  My instinct on this one says that somewhere in the guts of their code they need this conditional to evaluate to 'true'.  Sounds like a hack.

Comment: it's not about the purpose... even though that would help to understand the situation. I'm asking if that is even possible! The `prototype` property is non-configurable, so you can't just do `Array.protype = top.Array.prototype`. I don't think this is done by the JavaScript code, it must be done by the browser. I'd like to know if there are conditions where this is supposed to happen or if it's a browser bug.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'non-configurable'.  The Array prototype is mutable just like any Javascript object[1].  Take for instance this bit of code...

`Array.prototype.reflect = function(){console.log(this)};`

which will add the reflect method to all Array instances. Or...

`Array.prototype.pop = function(){alert('I broke it!');}`

which will break the 'pop' behavior of all Array instances (and likely cause you to receive unpleasant emails :) ).

[1] There are known hurdles extending the Array prototype, but that doesn't make the Array prototype untouchable, just difficult to extend.

Comment: that doesn't make the two prototypes pass strict equality! I think you're mistaking this question as one of the usual "how do i add a function to all arrays". The `prototype` itself is mutable, but as a property of `Array`, it is non configurable, which means it cannot be replaced with another object.

Comment: At this point I wonder if we are talking past each other.  Because clearly it's possible to replace pop with another object.
*example*
`Array.prototype.pop = function(){alert('replaced');return orig.call(this)};
['a','b','c'].pop();//alert, then returns "c"`
*example 2*
`foo = ['a','b','c'];
foo.pop = function(){alert('replaced');return orig.call(this)};
foo.pop()//alert, then returns "c"`

Comment: @Bruce.  I also get this from Chrome Developer Tools console.

`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Array.prototype, 'pop');`

**Output**
"{"writable":true,"enumerable":false,"configurable":true}"

Comment: **Edit**
`orig = Array.prototype.pop;`